# how to oversize an model and make it a solid object

Tags: modifiers

[image]I have a dental model and I tried to make a copy of teeth to be larger than their original size so I can make it solid and do boolean operation with the opposing teeth to make a stent.  I could not.  I tried to solidify but I does add from outside the teeth and inside the teeth as well so it will not fit in the mouth. [image] I tried extrude, but when the face extrude to one side of the axis, it is for example good from outside and the inside surface of the extrusion lies in the middle of the tooth, so again it does not fit.[image]
I did a cylinder, and did boolean for upper and lower teeth and could not cut the excess and finish it to look good[image]
I tried shrink fatten and failed to reach a result how to solve that. [image] Can I make an offset model and then make it a solid object to start cutting in it with the boolean modifier

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is a link to the blend file in my OneDrive.  The file is made with some add ons that I bought (blenderfordental) I do not know will it work in any other blender that does not have these add ons or not.  This is why I attached the pictures

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq4CBDoyfMe_s0nsxdLsf6rRf-kZ?e=klv60M

Comment: can you post .blend file or some screenshots?

Comment: I am very sorry, I am new and I prepared a word file with description and photos.  how can I attach it here.  I can attach the pictures separately but still I do not know hoe.  I will try to find out, or if you please guide me how to do

Comment: I found the way and attached some pics

Comment: Hey :). Please add more details about what *exactly* you are trying to achieve. When you say "I want to make the teeth larger" perhaps show an example of the desired result (photo, sketch, anything). Please also specify what is the *stent* in this case :). [Share your file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if it's small, or use Gdrive/onedrive...

Comment: what you want to do is, to increase the individual teeth size so that the gaps are covered and then boolean operation to cut the excess of the teeth right?

Comment: I attached more pictures and a link to the blend file